# How do I enter my PayPal account when filling out the form so that the person filling out the form can make proper payment?

Tags: cognito-forms

I've tried looking where I know to look.  But, being that I'm new to Cognito Forms and I've before experienced sites that want you to write more when the question, as I hope the solution, iOS simple, this is all I have to say.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do have some [help content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/53/collecting-payment/connecting-your-account#connect-to-paypal) on connecting your Cognito Forms Organization to your PayPal account. You will need to be on the Team plan or Enterprise plan level in order to connect your account, and use PayPal.